# Handling ActiveX events in Chrome 36

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, activex

**There are many threads about this**, but as far as I tried **all of them are outdated.**

I need a method to handle an **ActiveX** event on **latest Chrome versions**.

I have an ActiveX object named **csxi** for **using scanner** on browser, and I am having difficulties to scan multiple pages.

It works very well on **IE** as I can handle the event `onAcquire()` by writing this script block in the html page.

```
<script language="JavaScript" for="csxi" event="onAcquire();"
type="text/javascript">
    afterEachAcquire();
</script>
```

I looked for another ways to make it worki on Chrome and I found two other methods;

Handling the event using a syntax like `function csxi::onAcquire(){ //do something }`
but "::" is an undefined usage for javascript,

and adding an event handler to the ActiveX object. Unfortunately none of these methods worked.

Comment: Not going to work in Chrome, ActiveXs are for IE only.

Comment: There is a Chrome extension "IE Tab". I used it and script block handled the event. So there must be a way to use it.

Comment: IE Tab is using Windows' embedded IE engine to render. Not a native webkit renderer so the Script you using will work like on IE.